# Blender 2.8 + eGPU Vega 56 + Mac - issue rendering viewport on Rendered and Texture setting

Tags: 3d-view, gpu, osx

Just added eGPU with Vega 56 to my Mac setup and while it works in all but one aspect of Blender, there is an issue when I tell Viewport to use eGPU Vega 56 for Rendered and Textured views. Any idea if this is a bug in Blender 2.8 and will it be fixed?

No Issue when using shading or wireframe modes
[image]

Issues when using Textured or Rendered modes
[image]
[image]

Comment: As you are using the radeon prorender, I think you should report it to AMD support.

Comment: I will definitely do so, thanks